# нужно решить задачу с заполнением массива c++

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-studio

Помогите решить задачу, только изучаю c++
Заполнить произвольный массив размером N x N (N<10) по следующему правилу:
10000
00001
10000
00001
10000

Вот как я попробовал решить задачу, но это неверный код

```
const int n = 5;
   const int m = 5;
   int i, j;
   int a[n][m];
   int p = 0;
   
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   {
       for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
       {
           
           if ((j = 0) and (p = 0))
           {
               a[i][j] = 1;
               p = 1;
           }
           else if ((j = m- 1) and (p = 1))
           {
               a[i][j] = 1;
               p = 0;
           }
           else
           {
               a[i][j] = 0;
           }
           cout << " " << a[i][j];
       }
       cout << endl;
   }
```

Comment: Начните с замены присваиваний `(j = 0)` в шаё на сравнения `(j == 0)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в коде присваивание вместо сравнений. Кроме того, дополнительная переменная не нужна - просто смотрим, делится ли номер строки на 2 (четна - нечетна):

```
const int n = 5;
const int m = 5;
int i, j;
int a[n][m];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        if ((j == 0) and (i%2))
        {
            a[i][j] = 1;
        }
        else if ((j == m-1) and (i%2==0))
        {
            a[i][j] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            a[i][j] = 0;
        }
        cout << " " << a[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал быстрее _ без вложенного цикла и условий:

```
const size_t n = 5,  m = 5;    
int a[n][m] = { 0 };
/*int* p = a[0];
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   *p = 1;
    p += 2* m * (i & 1);
    *(p - 1) = 1;
}*/
```

Точнее, как правильно заметил `Harry`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    a[i][(i % 2) * (m - 1)] = 1;
```

Comment: Терзают смутные сомнения :) Итак, `i==0`. `*p = 1;` - OK, присвоение `a[0][0]`. Далее `p` не изменяется (`i&1 == 0`), так что `*(p-1)=1` присваивает за пределами массива, нет? Вот, я взял массив с лишней строкой и передал его в `p` со смещением на строку . Результат говорит сам за себя... https://ideone.com/jHkgvk

Comment: Тогда уж `for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i][i%2*(m-1)] = 1;`

Comment: @Harry, верно, сначала нужно инициализировать  a[0][0]. = 1, а потом начинать цикл с size_t i = 1. Я исправлю, спасибо

Comment: И не писать 2 раза :) - в том смысле, что у вас `n` итераций цикла, и в каждой итерации по 2 записи значения 1. Вроде как многовато... :) Дело в том, что каждая вторая итерация не меняет значение `p`, но запись все равно выполняется.

Comment: А как вы рекомендуете? Напишите в своем ответе, а я свой удалю

Comment: Да зачем удалять? а как я рекомендую - ну, я выше написал - замените свой цикл, например, на `for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i][i%2*(m-1)] = 1;`. Но если вы хотите именно через указатель - то я бы заменил цикл на такой: `for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { *p = 1; p += (2*m-2)*1-i%2)+1; }`

Comment: согласен, с массивами нужна внимательность....Просто, если сейчас исправить, то эти комментарии уже не нужны. А не лучше все оставить как есть,  а ваши комментарии будут исправлением ошибки?

Comment: Точно, нужна - я скобку пропустил :) - `for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { *p = 1; p += (2*m-2)*(1-i%2)+1; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
 const int n = 5;
 const int m = 5;
 const int w = 6;
 char a[n][w];
 int p = 0;
 int q = 1;

 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
         a[i][j] = '0';
         cout  << a[i][j];
      }
      cout  << " ";
  }


 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
      if(q%2) a[i][4] = '1';
      else a[i][0] = '1';
      q++;
      cout << endl;
 }

 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
         cout  << a[i][j];
      }
      cout  << " ";
  }
   cout << endl;
```

Comment: А почему присваиваются *символы* 1, а не числа? (о том, что использована магическая константа :) 4, я молчу...)

Comment: В условии не сказано какой тип данных у массива. Про магическую константу не понял. Поясните, пожалуйста. Я только учусь этой не простой науке.

Comment: Ну, если автор вдруг поменяет `m` на 8, то ваш код перестанет работать. Обычно такие константы - там, где лучше использовать именованные переменные - именуют "магическими", потому что потом с ними долго разбираться, что за магия спрятана за конкретным числом... Что до типа у автора - то не согласен, у него четко написано - `int a[n][m];`.

Comment: На счет магического числа понял. Спасибо. Я знаю про это, просто торопился скорее написать. А на счет типа массива я все же настаиваю что в задании не указано какого типа должен массив. ТС уже сам начал решать задачу с типом int. В задании говориться "заполнить произвольный массив размером N x N (N<10)". Произвольный массив.